# How to concat videos with different colour spaces?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

[image]I am trying to concatenate many videos together with the concat filter. The problem I have is that the colour of some of the videos is very washed out in the final output. I believe this is because the videos have different colour spaces. Some are B.709 and some are B.2020. The B.2020 videos are washed out.

I have tried converting the B.2020 videos to B.709 before concatenating by using the following command on each video but the outputs are still washed out:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf colorspace=all=bt709:iall=bt2020:fast=1 output.mov
```

It wasn't clear to me which way round the arguments should go so I also tried switching the `bt2020` and `bt709` terms but they still look washed out but with more saturation.

Is this the right approach? Am I missing some other arguments in order to convert the B.2020 videos to B.709 while preserving their colour?

I have attached a side by side of the original and converted video.

The metadata of the videos I am trying to concat are:

**Video 1**

- color_range=tv
- color_space=bt709
- color_transfer=bt709
- color_primaries=bt709

**Video 2**

- color_range=tv
- color_space=bt2020nc
- color_transfer=arib-std-b67
- color_primaries=bt2020